# Simulation data using a dataframe

Tags: r

I want to simulate an existing dataset to get the best model.Considering the following dataset and I want to create 100 or 1000 sample using this data in R. Any help?

```
x<-data.frame( A=c("A","B","M","N","P"),
B=c("G","N","P","R","I"),
C=c("T","F","L","U","U"),
D=c(9,12,13,13,12),
E=c(14,17,10,19,10),
F=c(10,12,19,17,15), 
G=c(7,12,10,14,15), 
H=c(18,19,19,12,12),
I=c("K","L","M","F","D"),
J=c("C","V","O","N","F"),
K=c("G","N","P","P","I"))
```

Comment: it's really not at all clear what you want to do.  The generic recipe for bootstrapping is `boot_data <- x[sample(nrow(x),size=nrow(x),replace=TRUE),]` ...

Comment: @Ben I want  to create say 1000 sample with 1000 rows using the data set provided to find out the best model for my data. This would help to find out the bias

Comment: @@  Ben Bolker , does  the function of set.seed (1) make sens in your codes ( if I want to use)?

Answer (score 1):

If you want 1000 data sets, try putting them all into list with this.

```
lapply(1:1000, function(i, x) x[sample(nrow(x), size=1000, replace=TRUE), ], x)
```

Although I'm not sure what the value of using a simulated data sets of size 1000 from a sample of fewer observations.  I believe Ben Bolker's recommendation of `size=nrow(x)` is probably the more sound way to approach this.